# ASP.Net MVC Usage confusion

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm in a situation where I would like to take a value from a page using JQuery, update the model with that value, call a method to update a different value in a model. Then call the controller to return a view with the new model.

I'm new to this so I imagine this is the wrong approach.

This is the View I have so far:

```
@using Cubic.OSS.SNMPMessageDuggerWebApplication.Models
@model SnmpModel
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "SNMP Message Debugger";
}

@section scripts
{

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {


        $("#input-button").click(function () {
            // This is where I want the process to start.
        });


    });

</script>

}


<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<div class="container-bar">
    <div id="input-bar">
        <p class="input-label">Enter SNMP Message: </p>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="300" id="input-area"></textarea>
        <br />
        <button id="input-button">Convert</button>
    </div>
    <div id="output-bar">
        <p class="output-label">Result: </p>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="300" id="output-area"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

My model looks like this:

```
public class SnmpModel
{

    public string SnmpMessageInput { get; set; }
    public string SnmpMessageOutout { get; set; }


   // I Imagine a method would be added here to transform the input

}
```

And this is the controller so far:

```
public class SNMPController : Controller
{
    // GET: SNMP
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


}
```

What I don't know how to do is: update the model with the returned JQuery, then refresh the page with the new model using the controller.

The input would be taken from the input text area, then transformed using code that was written in C# previously. This would be a method in the model I image. I have to use the code written in C# so I can't do the algorithm in js.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont do the page/view reload. Just update the desired value like this:

```
 function onChangeNumber() {
    var changedText = $("#PhoneNo").val();
    var CountryVal = $("#CountryCode").val();
    var CountryName = $("#appSelected option:selected").text();
    var ProductVal = $('#appSelected option:selected').val();
    url = '/controller/PhoneTextChanged';
    var data_to_send = {
        changed: changedText, ProductValue: CountryName
    };
    alert(changedText + CountryName);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: data_to_send,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data == "Invalid Number format") {
                alert("Invalid Number format");
            }

            else if (data == "hide") {
                $("#hiddenDiv").hide();
            }
            else {
                $("#hiddenDiv").show();
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Server error! try back later.");

        }
    });
};
```

In this code what im doing is, I am hiding or unhiding a  depending upon the result returned by the method i created in my controller i.e PhoneTextChanged.

I pass parameters to this method PhoneTextChanged and then i evaluate my results and then return the result from controller like this :

```
 return Json("no hide");
```

I hope you want to do the same stuff at your end. Let me know if you want to know more.

Comment: Sorry, I should've probably mentioned this. The reason I need to send the code to a model was because there is code that has been written in C# that I'm meant to use on the users input. I can't do the modifications in Javascript, I'm meant to reuse what was given in C#.

Comment: I'll add that to the bottom of my question

Comment: the code i mentioned is also using C# on the backend. that doesnt make the difference.